# CaptainCasa: Buffer file is not converted to .csv file

Tags: captaincasa

I am using captain casa with Java 11. Trying to download .csv file with large data volume.

I have used defaultBufferedStreamContent and have also set the file name using setFileName method.
But when I click export button, It downloads data in some internal .ccbuffer file.

When I am using url based session management, it is working as expected and data is downloading in .csv file.